# Modal only showing last in Database

Tags: php, html, database, bootstrap-modal

I am new to databases and PHP, so my knowledge of their integration is extremely limited. I have a list showing on my site and each item has a button that links to a modal. I am trying to have each modal open up correspond with the id of the item listed. Instead, it is only showing the last item in the database list.

I have tried adding code that I have seen from online searches, but nothing seems to work. I want to avoid AJAX, JS, and JQuery. I don't really think that it needs that. It seems to just be a syntax error.

```
    <div class="recentUploads col-md-8">

        <!-- Magic Key --- CONNECTS or PLUGS-IN to the DATABSE -->
        <?php include("_inc/database_key.php"); ?>

        <!-- REQUEST specific information -->
        <?
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `comic book collection` ORDER BY id";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>

        <!-- DISPLAY that specific information -->  
        <?php
            echo '<div class="comic_book_card row">';

                $id=$row["id"];

                echo '<div class="cover col-3"><img style="width: 100%;" src="'.$row["picture"].'"></div>';

                echo '<div class="comic-info col-8">';
                    echo '<h2>#'.$row["issue"].' '.$row["title"].'</h2>';
                    echo '<h6>'.$row["publisher"].' | '.$row["event"].'</h6>';
                    echo '<h6>'.$row["month"].' '.$row["day"].', '.$row["year"].'</h6>';


                    echo '<button id="modal-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details" >More Info</button>';
                    echo '<form><input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="'.$row["id"].'"</form>';
                echo '</div>';


            echo '</div>';

        ?>

        <!-- IM DONE - CLOSE the connection -->
        <?php
            }
            } else {
            echo "0 results";
            }
            $conn->close();
        ?>

    </div>
```

Details
        ×
      

      
        
          " allowfullscreen>
        
      

      
        Close

Comment: you get only last record from database with select query?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

***Try This Code :-***

```
 <div class="recentUploads col-md-8">
        <?php include("_inc/database_key.php"); ?>
        <?
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `comic book collection` ORDER BY id";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
           $output="";
           while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $id=$row["id"];

        $output.='<div class="comic_book_card row">
        <div class="cover col-3"><img style="width: 100%;" src="'.$row["picture"].'"></div>
        <div class="comic-info col-8">
        <h2>#'.$row["issue"].' '.$row["title"].'</h2>
        <h6>'.$row["publisher"].' | '.$row["event"].'</h6>
        <h6>'.$row["month"].' '.$row["day"].', '.$row["year"].'</h6>
        <button id="modal-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details" >More Info</button>
        <form><input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="'.$row["id"].'"/></form>
        </div></div>';

        ?>

         } 
    </div>

    <?php echo $output; ?>
```